# How to set in function javascript on wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website. I want to set a ten second countdown on each video, but i don't know how to set on function:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/299uW/)

```js
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = 'preRoll',
        defaults = {
            pre: 'PreRoll HTML Code',
            post: 'PostRoll HTML Code',
            timer: 15
        };
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }
    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            var player = $(this.element),
                message = player.text().split(/\[(.+)\]/),
                timer = this.options.timer,
                pre = this.options.pre,
                post = this.options.post;
            if (message[1] !== 'x')
            {
                timer = message[1];
            }
            player.html('<div id="preRoll_timer">' + message[0] + timer + message[2] + '</div>' + pre);
            setTimeout(function() {
                player.html(function() {
                    return post;
                });
            }, (timer * 1000));
            setInterval(function() {
                timer = (timer - 1);
                $('div#preRoll_timer').html(message[0] + timer + message[2]);
            }, 1000);
        },
    };
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);

$('#player').preRoll({
    timer: 10,
    pre: '<img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" />',
    post: '<iframe width="500" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4Ti70Uidal4"></iframe>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player">Your video will start playing in [x] seconds.</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: ok i have answered with CODE below

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the above code *added* to your wordpress site. To give you any help with that, we would need to see some relevant code from the site where you want to insert it.